# d3 year slider enables area in between steps

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, visualization

I'm trying to create a step slider in d3 (v5) with the years 2010 through 2015. (Using plugin d3-simple-slider)

```
  var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y");
  a1 = parseTime("2010")
  a2 = parseTime("2015")
  var sliderStep = d3
    .sliderBottom()
    .domain([a1,a2])
    .width(300)
    .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat('%Y'))
    .on('onchange', <stuff>
    });

  var gStep = d3
    .select('div#slider-step')
    .attr("class","slider")
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', 510)
    .attr('height', 100)
    .append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(30,30)');
```

The slider that is displayed however seems to enable the area in between the "steps" and the year also seems to move along. Is there a way to have only the exact points at the steps enabled? Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: I have tried adding ```.step(1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365) ``` : this disables the area in between but the year from 2013 appears as one less when selected ie. 2013 as 2012, 2014 as 2013, 2015 as 2014.

Comment: There is no slider method (`d3.sliderBottom`) in D3. If you're using a plugin, like `d3-simple-slider`, please edit your question showing us what plugin you're using, with a link to the plugin's page/docs as well.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado thanks for pointing out, (I'm new to d3) have added the info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is due to the leap year of 2012. To overcome this particular situation, you can add the step method as,

```
.step(1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 366)
```

But it would not make everything perfect. if you check the date changes, you will find that. If you only need to consider years, I think, it would be good to make an array of years as data and you can change that array using another function as you want according to the scenario.

Comment: Aaah THIS WORKED, thankyou! The idea of leap year had briefly come to my mind when I saw it staying on the same year only after 2012 but I didn't appreciate the thought at the time to try it out.